# Playing Flash ( having tweens and event handlers ) on Android

Tags: android, flash

I have some flash games with motion tweens and interactivity features. Is anyone aware if such a kind of flash animation would work correctly on a  Android 2.2 device.
Most of the articles I have seen is more about videos rather than considering Flash as an interactive animation platform

Answer (score 1):

*It does work for sure.*

*I am running Flash on almost every single platform.
I have Malata Zpad - based on Android 2.2 tablet, and i have none problems using flash's on it.*

*Aswell - the idea of Flash is "Build once, run everywhere" and it is so.*

Please - reference the browser you are using on your device, because there is a few browsers which doesnt offer directly running Flash, instead they is "emulating" only flash, which usually does not include executing the Flash script.

Aswell - it is usually a good practice to know what is your hardware specifications of the target platforms. Most of old ( pre-Tegra chips ) android devices have a considering low hardware specifications, if your target platform is with considering low hardware specifications, i would suggest you to reduce number of tweens.

Answer (score 0):

Aricles I've read about Flash for Android usually suggest to reduce the number of animations on the screen.
I think you need to do some benchmark and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what sort of animations you do have but if your application runs on mobile devices, you definitely should try The greensock tweening engine.

I used it for years now and it's very handy especially when I need to work with Flash Lite.
http://www.greensock.com/

Also I don't know whether there are any emulators but I use the Adobe Device Central. I don't know whether they have updated it with Android phones but maybe.

Good luck,
Rob